# Passing function to child component this.props.children method undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to pass a function to `this.props.children` with the following.

```js
updateBarTitle(barTItle){
   this.setState({barTItle});
}
render(){
   const children = React.Children.map(this.props.children, function (child) {
        return React.cloneElement(child, {
            updateBarTitle: this.updateBarTitle
        });
      });
   {children}
}
```

But I keep getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'updateBarTitle' of undefined`.

Also I would like to ask would this be the best approach? My goal here is to update the parent state based on a child value. So I was thinking either do this. Pass a parent ready made function then the child will update that, or access the child state by the parent. Examples would be of great help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` in your mapping function is not bound the correct context. You can bind it by passing `this` as 3-rd argument:

```js
const children = React.Children.map(this.props.children, function (child) {
    return React.cloneElement(child, {
        updateBarTitle: this.updateBarTitle
    });
}, this);
```

or use arrow function which does not steal context:

```js
const children = React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child) => {
    return React.cloneElement(child, {
        updateBarTitle: this.updateBarTitle
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks!, Would my current approach be correct in updating my parent component or should I rather just retrieve a state value from the child?

Comment: @Tony IMHO passing functions (handlers, actions) to the child props is just fine with react . and I would say its prefered way..